# DllImport C# to C++ with Memory Access Violation

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, extern

i have a problem with a dllimport, first the C++ code:

```
   extern "C" {
   __declspec(dllexport) int wmain(char* configr, char* path)
   {
     ILoggerPtr logger;

   try
   {        
     _bstr_t config(configr);
     _bstr_t srcFile(path); 
   }
```

My C# Code:

```
    [DllImport(@"Test.dll")]
    static extern int wmain(string config, string path);
```

The call for to C++:

```
    string path = "c:\\bmp\\" + im.ID_MOVIMENTO + "_gray.bmp";
    temp.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    int k = wmain("Brasil", path);
```

Oks, the problem, in the first conversion in C++ char* to _bstr_t have the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in CarregadorFotos.exe

Someone have any idea to manage this error?

Comment: Yet another case of a missing CallingConvention.Cdecl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper calling convention of unmanaged DLL function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208084/proper-calling-convention-of-unmanaged-dll-function)

Comment: Sorry friend, but don't work, now throw the excption in the start of function.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in CarregadorFotos.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x738) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 1):

Your C# signature should be:

```
  [DllImport(@"Test.dll")]
    static extern int wmain([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string config, 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string path);
```

or

```
  [DllImport(@"Test.dll")]
    static extern int wmain(IntPtr config,  IntPtr path);
```

and as Hans Passant said, use `CallingConvention.Cdecl` or you might get a "Unbalanced stack" exception

Comment: [DllImport(@"UrmTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern int wmain([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string config,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string path); don't work, and the other don't work to. The same error.

Comment: Some time gives me a error in xstring in the moemnt of conversion char to _bstr_t

Comment: so maybe it's not a marshalling error. You may have a bug in your C++ code.

Comment: oks, thanks, i have this conevertion  _bstr_t config(configr); configr its a char*. Nothing more before this convertion.