# Export C++ Named Shared Memory reader variable to a C# App

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I have Win32 C++ DLL that reads a named shared memory, I want to export these values that the app receives to a C# application.

Actually, I have this code, but when I will access the values in C# App, I receive this:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ETS2 Utilities.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

C++ code:

```c++
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl returnGear();
}

extern int __cdecl returnGear()
{
    return shared_memory->gear;
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("ETS2_Utilities_Plugin.dll")]
public static extern int returnGear();

void GetData()

{
    res = returnGear();
    lblMarcha.Text = "Marcha: " + res;
}
```

Comment: This question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208084/proper-calling-convention-of-unmanaged-dll-function (note the inclusion of `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in the `DllImport` attribute).

Comment: You need to debug the C++ code, clearly it is unhappy.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the "Enable native code debugging" option.  Set a breakpoint on the function's entrypoint to verify that the debugger is functional and see where it blows from there.

Answer (score 0):

The p/invoke has the wrong calling convention. It should be:

```
[DllImport("ETS2_Utilities_Plugin.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int returnGear();
```

However, I doubt that's your problem. I suspect that the real problem is that `shared_memory` is not pointing to valid memory. Quite likely is that `shared_memory` is `nullptr`.

As a quick test of the interop, replace your unmamaged function with this:

```
int __cdecl returnGear()
{
    return 42;
}
```

If this works then that tells you that the interop is fine, but your unmanaged library is not being initialised properly.

One final note, you used `extern` in your definition of the unmanaged `returnGear` function. That is a mistake. Remove it, as I have done above.

Comment: If I put return 42, this returns 42 in the C# Application.

Null Pointer? In a Console Application, if I do:

cout << shared_memory->gear;

The value is printed.

Comment: Where is shared_memory initialised?

Comment: David Heffernan:

telemetry_state_t *shared_memory = NULL;

and in the main():
shared_memory = static_cast<telemetry_state_t *>(MapViewOfFile(memory_mapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: `MapViewOfFile` likely returns `NULL`. Did you check that? If not why not? Always always always check for errors when calling Win32 functions.

Comment: But why in Console Application, when I do the cout << shared_memory->gear, this works?

Comment: I cannot see the relevant code. I answered the question you asked. You cannot expect us to debug and critique code that is not presented. I think we have done all that can be done here.

Comment: We don't need any more code. I think the question that you asked has been answered.