# C# callback from C inexplicably fails after many iterations

Tags: c#, c, dll, callback, unmanaged

I have a very straightforward C# delegate passed as a callback to an unmanaged .DLL written in C, which inexplicably crashes after a few hundred iterations (callbacks). C# first communicates the callback to C and then calls an infinite C-loop, which calls the callback every second.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class tst {
    public const String DLL_NAME = @"dll-tst3.dll";
    public delegate void CallBackType(Int32 fst, Int32 snd);

    [DllImport(DLL_NAME)]
    public static extern void SetCallback(CallBackType cb);

    [DllImport(DLL_NAME)]
    public static extern void UnmanagedInfiniteLoop();

    static UInt32 nCallbackCalls = 0;

    public static void CallBack(Int32 fst, Int32 snd) {
        Console.WriteLine("nCallbacks={0}, fst={1}, snd={2}",
               ++nCallbackCalls, fst, snd);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String logLine = String.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}", 
               dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"), fst, snd);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", logLine);
        GC.KeepAlive(callback); // prevent garbage collection
    }

    static CallBackType callback = new CallBackType(CallBack);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        SetCallback(callback); // register callback in C
        UnmanagedInfiniteLoop(); // C code calling callback indefinitely
    }
}
```

My C code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef void(__cdecl *callback_t) (int fst, int snd);

callback_t callback;

extern "C" //Every method defined in this block is not mangled 
{
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SetCallback (callback_t cb) {
    callback = cb;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl UnmanagedInfiniteLoop () {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    for (;;) {
        Sleep(1000);
        callback(a++, b++); // C# callback
    }
}
} //End 'extern "C"' to prevent name mangling
```

It fails, always around after 550 callbacks, with "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

```
nCallbacks=550, fst=549, snd=550
2013-11-24 00:12:34.509: 549, 550
nCallbacks=551, fst=550, snd=551
2013-11-24 00:12:35.510: 550, 551
nCallbacks=552, fst=551, snd=552
2013-11-24 00:12:36.511: 551, 552
```

At this point the above "A problem..." error message pops up.

It crashes after a fewer callbacks, if the C# CallBack does something more substantial, like writing (appending) logLine to a stream.

Note that additional decorations

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

do not help.

Stupid hypotheses:

1. One cannot call I/O functions from a C# callback.
2. In

   static CallBackType callback = new CallBackType(CallBack);

the destination object is being moved around by GC, since it has no knowledge whether it is being used by the unmanaged C code. After all, the C code just copies the reference to this object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  typedef void(__cdecl *callback_t) (int fst, int snd);
```

You have a mismatch on the calling convention on the *callback*.  This will imbalance the stack and will quickly crash your program when it underflows.  Fix:

```
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public delegate void CallBackType(Int32 fst, Int32 snd);
```

or on the C side:

```
  typedef void (__stdcall *callback_t)(int fst, int snd);
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution works fine (for > 30000 callbacks) and I will test the first one later. Do I understand it correctly that C# (rather than C) wants/needs/has to clean up the stack? Indeed, in my C# code above extern C-functions should be additionally decorated (in [DllImport]) with CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl? Indeed, in this case (Cdecl) the stack cleanup is performed by the caller (i.e., C#) and the callback function (in C) is decorated __stdcall (as you suggested), i.e., the stack cleanup is peformed by the called function (i.e., CallBack in C#).

Comment: Could you please suggest any reference reading about all this managed/unmanaged calls convention business. I read ~100 web pages explaining it, but it all looks as alchemistry.

Comment: You just need to have a match.  The default in C# pinvoke is __stdcall, the default in C is __cdecl so somebody has to alter their declaration.  It is up to you to choose which.  You'll find more alchemy in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664100/17034).