# Passing pointer as argument to native function with PInvoke

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, pinvoke

I need to call native function

```
long (WINAPI*)(long,long*);
```

In long* it will give me the result

i am doing this

```
[DllImport("mrfw.dll", EntryPoint = "_McammGetCurrentBinning@8")]
static long Get_Current_Binning(Int32, IntPtr);
```

but this call is not working

```
Int32 Camera_Index= 0;
Int32 Result;
IntPtr Result_Pointer = IntPtr(Result);

long Binning = Get_Current_Binning(Camera_Index, Result_Pointer);
```

I have the exception System.AccessViolationException
So, function can not write me the result.

How to do this?

Thank you.

---

Update

Hey guys.
I do not know what you all mean, but i did ask, what i did ask.

-I am using c++ cli. it is not c#

-I need pinvoke. I can not call unmanaget dll from cli project

-i did found the solution by doing this. You can delete my answers, give me the minuses, but it is working. It is so bad?

```
[DllImport("mrfw.dll", EntryPoint = "_McammGetCurrentBinning@8")]
static long Get_Current_Binning(Int32, IntPtr);

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 Int32 Camera_Index= 0;
 Byte* Result= new Byte(4);
 IntPtr Result_Pointer = IntPtr(Result);

 long Binning = Get_Current_Binning(Camera_Index, Result_Pointer);
}
```

Comment: The entrypoint name says that the function has **one** argument, not two.  Visible from the @4 postfix.  You are working from with bad documentation or just guessed wrong at the proper function pointer type for this function.  You could just try omitting the 2nd parameter as a wild guess, it certainly is never an IntPtr.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks to you i did fix the problem, but next did come. And one more question for you: how i can learn to read entery pont name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664100/17034

Comment: Than you. So, @8 is size of arguments. And what about AccessViolationException? How i can give to fuction memory, to write?

Comment: Why are you using PInvoke with C++/CLI? Does not make sense.

Comment: @leppie What is your solution?

Comment: In C++/CLI you should be able to call the function directly as far as I know.

Comment: @leppie Can you give more explenation about this, please? As i know in CLI(.NET) you need to make Wrapper to call native code.

Comment: Why cant you just do: `long result; cammGetCurrentBinning(index, &result)` in C++/CLI?

Comment: @leppie i hane only DLL file. How i can link name to DLL function?

Comment: What is odd here is that you show C# pinvoke. Where does that come from?

Comment: There's little point asking if you don't listen. That's not how to make the address of a long. Use `&` for that. And pinvoke is totally wrong here.

Comment: Pinvoke feeds my needs. It you, who is not reading. I did not asked about use it or not. And i do not need the address of the long. I need to solve access error.

Answer (score 1):

You are coding in mixed mode C++/CLI and there's no need for p/invoke. If what you have is a DLL without a .lib file, and a mixed mode C++/CLI program, then you have a couple of options.

1. Obtain or create a .lib file for the DLL. Then link to the DLL using implicit linking in the traditional way.
2. Link to the DLL using explicit linking with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

In either case you will be able to call the function like this:

```
long result;
long retval = Get_Current_Binning(0, &result);
// check retval for success, and if so the result contains the returned value
```

Comment: This is C++/CLI, so I am confused by all this p/invoke. Is it really needed? MC++ was fine mixing.

Comment: @leppie The pinvoke in the question is clearly C#. The question is a bit of a mess I do concede.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but tagged and the rest of the syntax looked a bit un C# like (his answer at least) :)

Comment: @leppie I've updated my answer to attempt to be schizophrenic

Comment: OK, but how it is better comparing PInvoke? it is more work: i need to make .lib and use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. What is the benefits of this?

Comment: You are just adding a layer of complexity by using p/invoke, one that you don't need. It will also get rapidly more complex to use p/invoke when you need more complex functions. Indeed when faced with complexity people often switch to C++/CLI.

Comment: Thank you for get a led answer. You mean more complexity for compiler, so longer execution time, or for coding? I think, what complex functions will be complex everywhere.

Comment: It will more complex to code, and perform worse, to use pinvoke.

Comment: Agree about the perform. But instead of making .lib i only need to make pinvoke in right format.

Comment: Making a .lib file is really easy. You just build a fake dll with empty stubs for your exports. Throw away the dll and keep the lib.

Comment: yes, but why to do something, if it not necessary to do it? It is really helping to solve something? And you code will not work in c++ cli in any way. It will have the another syntax. :)

Comment: It is handy for my in global scope of the project. But it not the main point. The question is "why i can not use 1 line solution"? It is so bad? Your code in this answer will cause compiler error in c++ cli.

Comment: You can do whatever you like. Including allocating a 4 byte integer on the heap instead of using `&` with a local variable. It's entirely up to you what you do.

Comment: It was not my dream to allocate bytes. The problem, what by using '&' i have AccessViolationException. It is my main question it this topic.

Comment: If that is so, and that really is the issue, then where is the code?

Comment: The line "static int Get_Current_Binning(int index, out int result);" will cause "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ref'". It is because of anohter sintax of c++ cli conmaring c#. Not important, becouse i am not using you code in any way. I have another question: how to replace memory allocation, if it is possible?

Comment: No, that code won't lead to a syntax error since it is C# code. Remember that there has been confusion over what language is being used. Declare a local variable and take its address using the `&` operator.

Comment: Thank you! You did push me to investigation and i just found the solution. Not something i will publish here. This question is in one step to delete. One more: you should not have confusion, because it was c++ in Tags.