# Why VC++ linker adds an underscore to the entry point?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

When I pass these arguments to the VC++ linker:

```
link D:\1.obj /OUT:D:\1.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:main
```

The linker actually treats the string "main" as if it were "_main" (if I were to enter /ENTRY:hello it will treat it as /ENTRY:_hello, etc.).

Why is that? and can I make the linker not add an underscore to the entry point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664100/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) ([more detailed info on VC name mangling here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling)). And I don't think you want to remove it.