# conversation with typedef variable in c++

Tags: c#, c++, variables, dll, typedef

i have c++ type definition like this

```
typedef void* ScreenNode;
```

and use it in my c++ code like this

```
ret = InitNode("factory", &g_screen_node, 128, 128, EN_C1Dev);
```

**EN_C1Dev is a ENUM

my typedef variable is a void pointer and  InitNode return a value by changing  pointer value "g_screen_node".

now i use this function in a dll inside a C# program with this definition

c++ code

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CB_initNode(ScreenNode* p_g_screen_node,int width,int heigth,EN_DevType EN_C1Dev)
    {
        int ret = 0;

```
    //InitNode ----------------------------------------------------------------
    ret = InitNode("factory", p_g_screen_node, 128, 128, EN_C1Dev);
    return ret;
}
```

dll definition class

```
[DllImport(dllName)]
        public static extern
            int CB_initNode(out IntPtr g_screen_node, int width, int heigth, EN_DevType EN_C1Dev);
```

and finally my main program

```
IntPtr g_screen_node = new IntPtr();
ret = BBIA.CB_initNode(out g_screen_node , 128, 128, EN_DevType.EN_C3Dev);
```

the **CB_initNode** function return error code and g_screen_node not return Expected value and stay on 0x00000000!

Comment: Don't use pointers in C# unless you *have* to. (Hint: You don't have to. Change the P/Invoke signature to use `ref int g_screen_node` instead and pass `ref ab`. This will not fix your error, but it's still something you should change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the parts of your question in order:

1. You should consult the documentation (or source code, if no documentation is available) of `InitNode` for the meanings of the input and output arguments of `InitNode`.  *Most likely* the method actually *allocates and initializes* a `ScreenNode` and returns an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to the caller -- one whose internal implementation is hidden.  However, there is not enough information in your question to determine this for certain.

   My answers to the remaining parts of your question assume that this is true.  If not, please update your question with appropriate documentation from `InitNode`, then we can take another cut at answering.
2. c++ code.  You need to decorate your function with [`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/02/780637.aspx):

   ```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CB_initNode(ScreenNode *p_g_screen_node,int width,int heigth, EN_DevType EN_C1Dev)
   {
       int ret = 0;

       //InitNode ----------------------------------------------------------------
       ret = InitNode("factory", p_g_screen_node, 128, 128, EN_C1Dev);
       return ret;
   }
   ```

   You also need to pass in a pointer to a `ScreenNode` (i.e. a double pointer) so that the pointer value set in `InitNode()` can be communicated out.
3. And then in your c# [extern declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660722/why-are-cdecl-calls-often-mismatched-in-the-standard-p-invoke-convention/15664100#15664100), you define the returned pointer as an [`out IntPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

   ```
   [DllImport(dllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern int CB_initNode(out IntPtr g_screen_node, int width, int heigth, EN_DevType EN_C1Dev);
   ```
4. Then in the main program:

   ```
   IntPtr g_screen_node;
   var ret = BBIA.CB_initNode(out g_screen_node, 128, 128, EN_DevType.EN_C3Dev);
   ```

Then later, if you need to pass a `ScreenNode` back to the same library, you would use the `IntPtr` previously returned.  And when done with it, don't forget to free it -- presumably the library you are using has a method for that also.

Finally, you don't state what `EN_DevType` is, but I am guessing that it is an `enum`.  If so, you should check you have the correct values.  If not an `enum`, then my answer to your question might need to be updated.

**Update**

If `InitNode` needs to know the current value of the incoming `void **` pointer because it is preallocated or preinitialized, the signatures would be as follows:

```
    [DllImport(dllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int CB_initNode(ref IntPtr g_screen_node, int width, int heigth, EN_DevType EN_C1Dev);

    IntPtr g_screen_node = // However you initialize are supposed to allocate it using your library, possibly just IntPtr.Zero.
    var ret = BBIA.CB_initNode(ref g_screen_node, 128, 128, EN_DevType.EN_C3Dev);
```

In order for us to answer in confidence rather than guessing, please update your question with the documentation for `InitNode`, and let us know what functions you are calling before the call to `InitNode`, if any.

Comment: hi thank for your replay. all of your suggest is correct.but your resolve not work. in c++ after call InitNode, *p_g_screen_node change and take a value but in c# that is 0x00000000. it may be for access protection to IntPtr g_screen_node variable!!!

Comment: @MohammadFarahani - answer updated.  However, if you want us to answer with more confidence, please update your question with documentation for `InitNode()`.

Answer (score 0):

`&g_screen_node` is used to pass the address of `g_screen_node` to the `InitNode` function. This is usually means the parameter will be used as an output parameter.

As to why you're getting an error code, I'll take a stab and say your call to `BBIA.CB_initNode` needs `&ab`, not `ab`