# Pass C# Byte[] to C++ API

Tags: c#, c++

I have to pass an Byte array containing an MAC-Address to a C++ Method. Since I don't have much experience with working with c
C++ APIsI don't know how to do this. I've tried to pass the array itself, but got an `invalid parameter code` **as response from the API**. I've also tried to create an `IntPtr` but to no avail.
I know that the problem is that C++ can't handle managed datatypes such as arrays, so I've to create a unmanaged array somehow, I think.

Here is the definition of the C++ Method:

```
ll_status_t LL_Connect(
ll_intf_t intf, 
uint8_t address[6]);
```

The array in C# is defined the following way:

```
Byte[] addr = new Byte[6];
```

Of course, the array is not empty.

Comment: byte[] in C# to unsigned char* in C++ is what I use to do this

Comment: You have to create an unmanaged array, C#'s arrays are not the same as C++'s.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't change anything in the c++ part. @SombreroChicken, i know that, i don't know how to create an unmanaged array.

Comment: Using byte[] in the C# code is the correct way.  Getting the [DllImport] declaration wrong is the standard explanation.  We can't see it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660722/why-are-cdecl-calls-often-mismatched-in-the-standard-p-invoke-convention/15664100#15664100

Comment: I would look into where exactly the "invalid parameter code" error is coming from. Is it coming from the C# code trying to call the C++ code or from the C++ code itself. Maybe you are passing parameters fine but the code just doesn't like the parameters you are passing. Also is it possible to debug the C++ code at all and see what parameters it's receiving?

Answer (score 4):

For example:

C++

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void GetData(uint8_t* data, uint32_t length)
    {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        data[i] = i;
    }
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("LibName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void GetData([In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] data, uint length);
```

And use in C#

```
 byte[] data = new byte[4];
 GetData(data, (uint)data.Length);
```

If you have an array fixed length, for example:

C++

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void GetData(uint8_t data[6])
    {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        data[i] = i;
    }
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("LibName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void GetData([In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 6)] byte[] data);
```

And use in C#

```
 byte[] data = new byte[6];
 GetData(data);
```

For your case:

```
    [DllImport("LibName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int LL_Connect(byte intf, [In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 6)] byte[] address);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! unfortunally i can't change any of the existing c++ code. As stated above the method to be called is defined in the following way: `ll_status_t LL_Connect(
ll_intf_t intf, 
uint8_t address[6]);` ll_intf_t is just a Byte... so i have to pass my array somehow.

Comment: For this case use:
        [DllImport("LibName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int LL_Connect(byte intf, [In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 6)] byte[] address);

        See my edit commet.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Seems like a great approach! Still getting the invalid parameter response, but I'm going to look into that tomorrow. **thank you very much!!**