# Pinvoke native method with pascal callingconvention

Tags: c#, pinvoke, stdcall

I have an old c++ librrary and all of methods exports with pascal calling convention,
As i know c# marshaller does not support pascal calling convention,
Can i use stdcall on c# side and pass parameters in reverse order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pascal` was a 16-bit calling convention, in 32-bit code it was replaced by `__stdcall`.  The identifier was retained for source compatibility.   CallingConvention.StdCall is the default for pinvoke so nothing special needed.

You can find out more about DllImport.CallingConvention in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15664100/17034), it mentions pascal.